# Can we index the WARC files directly into Solr?

Tags: solr, indexing, warc

Can we index the *WARC* files directly into Solr without extracting and *storing* some intermediate files (ex. *html* format) from the WARC files first on the hard disk?

In other words, can we index those files without storing anything on the hard disks?

Answer (score 3):

We have developed the [Web Archive Discovery](https://github.com/ukwa/webarchive-discovery) toolkit to exactly this. It uses Apache Tika and combines it with the WARC/ARC readers and some other utilities and generates suitable records and post them to Solr.

The [quick start](https://github.com/ukwa/webarchive-discovery/wiki/Quick-Start) should help if you want to try it out.

Answer (score 0):

You should do it on the client, as it is not clear what kind of schema you would want for those files. Then, you can just expand the content into memory in a streaming fashion, process it with client-side Tika if required and send whatever document representation you want to Solr.